# Form submission with $router.push() doesn't work again after backing the history on Safari

Tags: vue.js, safari, nuxt.js

I'm working with Nuxt and Vuetify, and here are my simplified codes:

```html
<template>
  <v-form @submit.prevent="formSubmit">
    <!-- some input elements -->
    <v-btn type="submit">Submit</v-btn>
  <v-form>
</template>
```

```html
<script>
export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    confirmMsg() {
      // ..
      return 'some confirm message';
    }
  },
  method: {
    formSubmit() {
      if (confirm(this.confirmMsg)) {
        this.$router.push({ path: `/someroute/${this.someVar}` };
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Itself works pretty well.

But after submitting form (== `$router.push()`) and coming back on the history,
the form cannot submit again on certain environment.

I checked it on Windows 10(Chrome, Edge) and iPhone 8+(iOS 15.3)(Chrome, Safari),
and only iPhone-Safari didn't pop the confirm message up.

(I guess Safari doesn't fully support JavaScript - I have another issue..)

I once made this feature without form submission but only with button-click event, but in this case I had to validate the form by myself.
I think it's quite wasteful.

---

In summary:

1. Submit form with `$router.push()`
2. Back the history (not with script, just on browser)
3. Resubmit the form -- it doesn't work only on Safari(iPhone 8+, iOS 15.3)

How can I fix it? .. or can I fix it?

Comment: Sometimes the browser will [not display multiple alert dialogs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm); maybe that's what's happening here? Can you set a breakpoint in the `formSubmit` method to check if it's being called?

Comment: @DecadeMoon As I wrote, it works very well on other environments. There is only one comfirm message. I cannot check what really happens on Safari... Can I use Developer Tools on mobile Safari?

Comment: [Yes](https://betterprogramming.pub/debugging-your-iphone-mobile-web-app-using-safari-development-tools-71240657c487). Whether or not the browser suppresses multiple alerts is up to each browser.

Comment: @DecadeMoon I've also searched about it and and it seems only available on Mac (I don't have Mac)...

Comment: You can do something else like adding `<div>{{ message }}</div>` in the template and setting `message = 'called'` when the method is executed (since you can't `console.log` either)